# find error in twitter integration

Tags: android, twitter

i m new in  android and integrate twitter api but find error 
Could not find class 'twitter4j.TwitterFactory', referenced from method net.londatiga.android.TwitterApp.

below code:

```
mTwitter = new TwitterApp(this, twitter_consumer_key,twitter_secret_key);//here find error

            mTwitter.setListener(mTwLoginDialogListener);
```

how to fix this issue but all 4 lib adding but run time find this error.
please help me out ...

Comment: Do you have the Twitter4j Library downloaded and added it to the classpath ? If no Add the Library to the classpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to adding the JAR file to the project you have to make sure that it will be included in the apk file:
Go to your project properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export tab, and ensure the box next to the twitter4j JAR file is checked.

Comment: yaa...i have added Twiiter4j-core-2.1.11.jar in Order and export tab

Comment: try renaming the "lib" folder name to "libs".

Comment: when i made "lib" to "libs" folder then find new error in run time here is declare-"Could not find class 'twitter4j.http.AccessToken', referenced from method "   ,,i added 4 jar file in  libs folder .one is httpclient-4.0.1.jar,signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar,signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar,twitter4j-core-2.1.11.jar